# I am very green on jsoup, and i cannot get Stcok price on website

Tags: java, html, jsoup

i am trying to get the stock price (eg.193.600) from http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=700

And i have the following code:

```
private String url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=700";

Elements answerers = document.select("div.data-row div.C.font28.C.bold .span .span");
```

But it only return `null`

I have also tried 
Elements answerers = document.select("td.styleA span.Price.down2");
return 
run:
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

and 
Elements answerers = document.select("td.styleA");
return
run:
 
 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS selector:

```
Elements answerers = document.select("td.up, td.down");
```

Comment: sorry.................. 
what i need is the PRice in selector "#StkDetailMainBox > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.styleA > span.Price.down2"

i am very green in jsoup, what is the selector i should use?

Comment: @WaiHung I'm sorry but I can't find any text using your CSS selector. The last level (`span.Price.down2`) is not found.

Comment: I have also tried Elements answerers = document.select("td.styleA span.Price.down2"); return run: null BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

and Elements answerers = document.select("td.styleA"); return run:     BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Thank you so much

i have added the picture in my question
the highlight part is what i need 

thx

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=700";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element table = doc.select("table[class=figureTable]").first();
    Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td[align=right]").iterator();
    iterator.next();// this is nominal column
    iterator.next();// this is turnover column
    System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
    System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
    System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
    System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
    System.out.println(iterator.next().text());
}
```